# Combining Header and Pose to make Posestamped

Tags: pose, posestamped, rospy, nav-msgs, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am trying to a node that publishes posestampted messages to a topic when a float is the value of 1.0 on a different topic.

Could any of you kind people help me with where I am going wrong? Please find a picture on the link below..

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vn3gcg6ixijir6g/HELP.png?dl=0

I believe the problem is wrong syntax on line 16, causing frame_id: odom, position:

rather than causing frame_id: odom
position:

Please forgive me for being such a python newbie.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201188/combining-header-and-pose-to-make-posestamped/) by [MDXLukeBennett](https://answers.ros.org/users/21402/mdxlukebennett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To publish it needs an object of the message type. Try something like

```
PS = PoseStamped()
```

and

```
PS = PoseStamped(msg.header, msg.pose.pose)
```

---

Originally posted by [Girts L](https://answers.ros.org/users/3081/girts-l/) with karma: 196 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1